# Edit not possible through account

Tags: support, suggested-edits, user-accounts, edits

I'm not able to edit the question. Can anyone tell me what's the reason behind that? On hove that it will be show "Account is not allowed to suggest edits"

Comment: According to [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2884813#./2884813?&_suid=1378819657416012076473112505026), you've had 15 edits approved, and 12 rejected.  You've incurred a suggested edit ban, either automatic or assigned by a moderator.

Comment: then how it will be reolved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have been temporarily banned from suggesting edits, as too many of your suggestions have been rejected.

You appear to be only adding JSFiddle links; that is not a good use of edit suggestions. In fact, it appears that is [all you do with your edits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2331073/subhash?tab=activity&sort=suggestions).

Edit suggestions should address *multiple* problems in posts. JSFiddle links are perhaps better left in a comment.

The ban will automatically be lifted in a week or so; the goal of the ban was to make you stop and try and figure out *why* you were banned. That goal has been met; you stopped and asked for an explanation here.

Comment: then how it will be resolved?

Comment: By you waiting for the ban to be lifted, automatically.

Comment: how many day it will take?

Comment: One week, 7 days.

Comment: The first time. Aren't they incremental, the bans?

Comment: @J.Steen: Not to my knowledge, not for editing bans. I think you are thinking about temporal suspensions instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah yes, that's it, the suspensions.

Comment: @J.Steen: 'temporary', not 'temporal', of course. I'd love to ban someone to a different era!

Comment: @MartijnPieters I quietly ignored that. Even if you have an awesome point. =>